# Ubuntu 13.04 Wifi not discovered

Tags: 13.04, wireless, drivers, usb

I first started using Ubuntu at v13.04 last monday straight onto my new computer, it has only seen Ubuntu. When i bought the desktop i also purchased a D-Link DWA-123 Model USB wifi adapter. It was discovered (although very slow) when using my live-cd to install Ubuntu, however after installation it stopped all together. I then moved my desktop to the router and used Ethernet to run updates and after these updates the wifi adapter was discovered again, however due to playing around with endless "fix"s all over the ask Ubuntu forums i believe i may have  mixed up some of the setting around for my drivers. When i start up my desktop my D-link adapter is undiscovered, after openning the terminal and using "sudo modprobe rt2800usb" it is discovered but is very slow and  i have attempted to download games in steam and watching the download rate flat line for a few seconds  then spike up to maybe 100-200kb/s then flat again. Using  my laptop at the same location running  win7 i can download at a rate of 400kb/s+ actual download rate through steam, and the  internet connection on it is fine.

After having no luck with finding a fix i went out today and purchased a TP-Link TL-WN823N usb wifi adapter. According  to the ubuntu or linux compatability page (don't remember which one i was referencing) all models around  this one have been reviewed and have been supported for plug and play working  at high speeds. I plug it into my desktop and it is undiscovered, i believe from all the  forum scrolling i have done that it is a driver issue. As i said this is my first time running Ubuntu and  i am very much over this wifi problem (also my sound isn't working, and i have gone into alsamixer and turned auto-mute off, but this is a secondary problem, need wifi working  asap). I am not overly familiar with the terminal commands for Ubuntu, so whoever reads this post and has help to offer may you please thoroughly explain what terminal commands etc. i should do to show drivers or make changes as you instruct. Will be checking this constantly so will has fast replies and be so very grateful to anybody who can help me fix this.
That is:
 1. Get TP-LINK TL-WN823N USB detected and at high speed.
 2. If no chance of getting TP-LINK to work, fix D-LINK (certain TP-LINK will be  easier)
 3. Fix no-sound issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Ubuntu 13.10 just released, so you may want to install that instead as it has a newer kernel with newer drivers which may have likely solved your issues. However, if you still want to install Ubuntu 13.04, read ahead.

Run `ifconfig` and check if wlan0 has any dropped packets. If so, lower the MTU in your network settings.

Add `modprobe rt2800usb` to /etc/rc.local before exit 0. You can edit text files with the command line with `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`. rc.local executes any commands listed inside of it on boot, so you won't have to manually modprobe it.

You can use `lspci` to list all of your hardware, and if you pipe `lspci` to `grep` you can only show lines that include a certain string, such as `lspcie | grep Network`, `lspci | grep Wireless`, `lspci | grep VGA`, or `lspci | grep Audio`.

If you want to install the latest kernel 3.12-rc5: `cd /tmp; wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc5-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200rc5-generic_3.12.0-031200rc5.201310131952_amd64.deb; wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc5-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200rc5_3.12.0-031200rc5.201310131952_all.deb; wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc5-saucy/linux-image-3.12.0-031200rc5-generic_3.12.0-031200rc5.201310131952_amd64.deb; sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb`

Comment: I am upgrading to 13.10 now at 30kb/s.

Comment: I ran the upgrade but i didn't have enough space on my root partition (i have a ssd for system and hdd for home), so i went and put in my live-cd and  used gparted to increase partition size... and when i rebooted my pc afterwards, with no live  cd... the TP-Link adapter lit up for the first time, however no networks available. Put my D-Link one in, enter the sudo modprobe rt2800usb and the D-link works with the networks being available. So i will run the upgrade now, but wanted to let you know that the TP-Link is now being recognised but not networking (i don't know if i have to enable it).

Comment: To enable networking via NetworkManager, run the following: `sudo sed -i 's/managed=false/managed=true/g' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` then reboot.

Comment: I will try that asap, just waiting for this upgrade to finish dling, been going for hours, got a loong way to go.

Comment: I ran the command you suggested then upgraded and it now works, thank you so much.